# Azure Remote directory navigation

Tags: powershell, azure

When I startup PowerShell from within my Azure Portal I can readily navigate to my Storage Accounts and files.

When running Powershell from my laptop, and logging into Azure using "Login-AzureRmAccount", I cannot do the same thing.  My prompt is always "PS C:>" so any dir command is executed on my laptop rather than actually "inside" Azure.

What am I doing wrong and how can I navigate the Azure file system?

Comment: You'll need to create a PS drive from a provider. SHiPs was created to do e exactly this, take a look:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/10/19/navigate-azure-resources-just-like-a-file-system/

Comment: @trebleCode - That did it!  Thank you!  I don't think I would have found that on my own, at least not in any sort of reasonable time frame.

How do I flag your comment as "Accepted Answer"?

Comment: I'll post as a solution if you'll mark it as one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a PS drive from a provider. SHiPs was created to do e exactly this, take a look:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2017/10/19/navigate-azure-resources-just-like-a-file-system/